# switch-case with return and break

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Just out of curiosity, I often see situations like:

```
switch(something) {
    case 'alice':
        return something;
    break;
}
```

Where the `break` seems to be completely unnecessary, is there any reason for it to be there anyway?

Comment: This is _probably_ just to prevent against errors that would result from copy/pasting and/or haphhazardly modifying that code in the future.  Looks like a good safety net to me.

Comment: Given the indentations, it may just be a stylistic choice -- using the `break` as the end of a suggested [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). But, the `break` is unreachable code after a `return` statement. So, it won't do anything; but it won't hurt anything either.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `break;` statement may have been there before the `return` statement was introduced. As such, it has become redundant and can be removed.

In fact, when you run that code through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/), it will show this error:

> Unreachable 'break' after 'return'.

Whether or not to heed this advice is up to you; it could be helpful during development if you're trying out a few things before settling on a particular style.

This is an alternative writing style that some might argue is a better practice:

```
var retval = null;
switch (something) {
    case 'alice':
        retval = something;
        break;
    // ...
}
return retval;
```

Comment: So some people (jslint) actually consider the notation an *error* +1 for the hint

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus Well, that's how Crockford feels about these things apparently :)

Answer (score 8):

`break` tells javascript to stop evaluating cases in the `switch` block. Code execution continues past the closing `switch` bracket. The `return` statement in the example code will indeed prevent further of anything past it, including other `case` statements and anything following the `switch` block.

I put a `break` statement in every case by habit. If I wrote a case without a `break` then I might copy and paste blocks of code around in the future and the lack of a `break` statement would become a bug like so:

```
function whereLivesA(species){
  switch(species){
    case 'worms': 
      // Relying on return to prevent further code execution within the switch
      // block works but is ~bad~ smelly (according to plato :D)
      var habitat = 'dirt'
      return (species + ' live in ' + habitat);
    case 'bees':
      var habitat = 'hive';
      break;
  }
  // Stuff to do after the switch statement (unless you returned already)
  var str = species+' live in '+habitat;
  return str;
}
console.log('whereLivesA');
console.log(whereLivesA("worms"));
console.log(whereLivesA("bees"));
  /* Output:
    whereLivesA
    worms live in dirt
    bees live in hive
  */


function whereLivesB(species){
  switch(species){
    case "worms": 
      // what if future code changes remove `return` and don't add `break`?
      // return (species + ' live in ' + habitat)
      var habitat = 'dirt';
      // break;
    case "bees":
      var habitat = 'hive'
      break;
  }
  // Stuff to do after the switch statement (unless you returned already)
  var str = species+' live in '+habitat;
  return str;
}
console.log('whereLivesB');
console.log(whereLivesB("bees"));
console.log(whereLivesB("worms"));
  /* Output:
    whereLivesB
    bees live in hive
    worms live in hive
  */


function whereLivesCorrect(species){
  switch(species){
    case "worms": 
      var habitat = 'dirt';
      break;
    case "bees":
      var habitat = 'hive'
      break;
  }
  // Stuff to do after the switch statement (unless you returned already)
  var str = species+' live in '+habitat;
  return str;
}

console.log('whereLivesCorrect');
console.log(whereLivesCorrect("bees"));
console.log(whereLivesCorrect("worms"));
  /* Output:
    whereLivesCorrect
    bees live in hive
    worms live in dirt
  */
```

JS newbies: If you don't want to save it to a file and run `node filename`, you can press F12 and paste this script or other self contained scripts into your browser's console to run it.

If you use node.js you can also type `node` at a command line to start a `node` console and paste it there.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` keyword is used to end the statement, or exit out of the loop so it doesn't continue running.

for example:

html

```
what's your age?: <input type="text" id="ageOf"><br>
<input type="submit" onSubmit="postReply();">
<div id="reply"></div>
```

js

```
function postReply() {
  let ageOf = document.getElementById('ageOf');
  let response = document.getElementById('reply');

  switch(true) {

    case ageOf<18:
      response.innerHTML = "Keep practicing young padewan.";
      break;

    case ageOf>18 && ageOf<45: 
      response.innerHTML = "Much too learn, you have.";
      break;

    case ageOf >= 45:
      response.innerHTML = "You have sage wisdom.";
      break;

    default:
      response.innerHTML = "";
      break;
  }
}
```

so on submission, the form should call the `function postReply()`, check the user answer and depending on the value, it should return one of those statements.

Comment: Are those conditions after the case labels actually valid syntax?  `ageOf < 18` looks dubious to me.  Also, the OP's question really just pertains to why somebody would use a `break` statement after a `return` statement.

Comment: A) the cases are not enclosed in curly brackets B) You must pass literals to `case`. e.g. instead of `case 1: ageOf<18{}` you would do `var s = 'young'; if(age>18){s='medium'}; if(age>45){s=old'}` and then `switch(s){ case 'young': ...; break; case 'medium'... }`

Answer (score -3):

the case is actually very necessary

You have a case, then you need to break from that case or else the other cases are picked up as well.

using cases is most often considered bad practice, stay away from them as much as possible.

```
switch(casein){
case 1:{
break;
}
case 2:{
break
}
}
```

Comment: Well, once 'return' is called the function stops executing

Comment: Could you explain why *using cases is most often considered bad practice*? Also, why the `{}` inside your cases?

Comment: @user2701974 I think you may have misunderstood the question. It's asking about the use of `break` after a `return`. The `switch..case` is just for context. Also, `switch` blocks aren't universally considered bad practices; they just aren't as often in preference over alternatives.

Comment: I think case statements are fine as long as they can't be replaced by refactoring and/or applying OOP concepts.

Comment: nono, i am saying they are considered bad practice because people tend to use them over more complex and neater code. overall the functionality would be the same, but this is more for sequential programming. i used the {} because i was clarifying where the case begins and ends, they are not needed.